# How to fix: The attempt to mount file system with type vfat in SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux

I got this error when I tried to boot Kali Linux on my laptop,

```
The attempt to mount file system with type vfat in SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed
```

[image]

Comment: Found this Article :read this one might be helpful for you :https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331303/the-attempt-to-mount-a-file-system-with-type-vfat-in-scsi1-0-0-0-partition-1?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass this error message by changing the bios setting of my DELL laptop.
I tried to reduce the UEFI setting to its minimum security, but I finally worked when I used the legacy boot mode.
Hope this helps others

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Just a friendly warning: Kali isn't a desktop distro, it's a security professionals' toolbox. It's not in any shape or form newbie-friendly. A lot of things are intentionally broken, as they're either irrelevant or pose a security threat for the intended purpose. As per the devs [_Even for experienced Linux users, Kali can pose some challenges._](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) so unless you're fairly well-versed with Linux, expect a heap of headaches. Getting familiar with the [documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs) is pretty much a must.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this error is probably that you have selected to create a new ESP partition and to mount it to `/boot/efi`, but forgot to tell the installer that a filesystem should be created on the partition first (known as "formatting the partition" in other operating systems).

Go back to the partitioning step as it suggests, select the ESP partition, and ensure its `Format the partition:` setting says `yes, format it`. Because formatting a pre-existing partition can be a destructive action, it requires an explicit answer.

(The fact that the first partition on the first disk is getting reformatted suggests that the any previous OS on this system is getting overwritten. If that was not your goal, **STOP NOW** and use [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or similar tool to try and recover your previous partitioning, as at least your original partition table should be already overwritten at this point.)